# git merge only additions

Tags: git, merge

I have a library I've been using in different projects that I've been updating as needed. Because I forgot to copy to some changes I ended up with two files with different additions that I had only added to.

Because I was planning on making a git repo for this library anyway I made one, added the first file, added the second file on a branch and merged them. This left me with a copy of the second file, not a merged together file.

So instead what I ended up doing is creating a new repo with a blank file in it, then copying the first file into a new commit, then checking out the blank file commit, then copying the second file in and making a new branch, then merging. This caused a merge conflict but after I simply removed the 
`<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======` and `>>>>>>> <branch name>` lines git had inserted I had the file I wanted.

I'm wondering if there was a better way to do this? Particularly if this happened again with multiple files. I tried a visual merge tool but it split chunks across function boundaries so I would've had to do it more manually.

Edit: examples of what I had and what I wanted.

I had two files (pseudocode):
File 1

```
defmodule foo

foo.bar = ...

foo.baz = ...

return foo
```

File 2

```
defmodule foo

foo.bar = ...

foo.qux = ...

return foo
```

Then I wanted to merge these into one file. Since the new functions (baz and qux) didn't call each other I would have been fine with either

```
defmodule foo

foo.bar = ...

foo.baz = ...

foo.qux = ...

return foo
```

or

```
defmodule foo

foo.bar = ...

foo.qux = ...

foo.baz = ...

return foo
```

Since I've only added to these files it seems like I should be able to get my desired file without having to cut and paste manually, and the trick with the empty file and two branches from that feels a overly complicated and doesn't scale well with multiple files. So I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Do you mean that, before making a new repo, you had: (1) a common merge base with files `A` and `B`; (2) a branch where you made some additions to file `A` but left file `B` untouched; and (3) a branch where you made some additions to file `B` but left file `A` untouched?  And if so, do you further mean that what you wanted was for git to somehow take "additions to `A`" and "additions to `B`" and add them both to the base version of `A` and leave the base version of `B` alone?

Comment: ... On re-reading your question, I don't think that's what you mean at all, but I still have no idea what you *do* mean.  I think you need a more precise description.  It would be even better if you included a sequence of git commands that set up the situation you would like resolved (perhaps with some trivial files, but set up as a small self-contained complete example).

Comment: Hopefully these examples clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I made this up as the [SSCCE / MVCE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/1256452).  We start with a repository with a `README` in `master`:

```
$ mkdir mergesamp
$ cd mergesamp
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../mergesamp/.git/
$ cat << END > README
> We put a dummy README file into the base,
> to get an initial commit.
> END
$ git add README && git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 40d9565] initial
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

Now we make a new branch `b1` and create `file1`:

```
$ git checkout -b b1
Switched to a new branch 'b1'
$ cat << END > file1
> defmodule foo
> 
> # We'll put a bunch of stuff in here
> # so that git can detect renames.
> # Files that are very short, that are
> # in fact renamed and modified, can
> # get missed because git does not
> # see that they are at least 50% matching
> # between the "before" and "after" versions.
> 
> foo.bar = ...
> 
> foo.baz = ...
> 
> return foo
> END
$ git add file1 && git commit -m 'add file1'
[b1 f603e15] add file1
 1 file changed, 15 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
```

Then we go back to master and create a new branch `b2` to hold `file2` (I use a slight shortcut here, creating `b2` starting at the commit identified by `master` rather than using two separate git commands):

```
$ git checkout -b b2 master
Switched to a new branch 'b2'
$ cat << END > file2
> defmodule foo
> 
> # This is the b2 version of file1.
> # We'll put a bunch of stuff in here
> # so that git can detect renames.
> # Files that are very short, that are
> # in fact renamed and modified, can
> # get missed because git does not
> # see that they are at least 50% matching
> # between the "before" and "after" versions.
> defmodule foo
> 
> foo.bar = ...
> 
> foo.qux = ...
> 
> return foo
> END
$ git add file2 && git commit -m 'add file2'
[b2 01ef1ca] add file2
 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file2
```

Let's see where we are now:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* 01ef1ca (HEAD -> b2) add file2
| * f603e15 (b1) add file1
|/  
* 40d9565 (master) initial
$
```

At this point we want to get back on `master` and make git merge `file1` and `file2`.  But of course there's no common base version of the file in `master`, so a simple `git merge` won't work.

(Aside: maybe we just want to merge `b2` into `b1`, or `b1` into `b2`.  I didn't find this clear from your original, which is why this kind of SSCCE / MVCE is a good idea.  Fortunately it won't matter for the ultimate solution here.)

There are multiple ways to handle this.  Perhaps the simplest from a blue-sky "thinking about it" point of view would be to go back to master, create a common base file, then rebase the two branches onto this point so that they *do* have a common base file.

This is, however, the wrong way.  Nonetheless let's show it...

#### The wrong way

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git checkout b1 -- file1
$ git commit -m 'copy b1 file1 to common base'
[master 71b0f5e] copy b1 file1 to common base
 1 file changed, 15 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
```

Note that this new commit in `master` has the exact same `file1` as in `b1`, so when I do a rebase I'll have to preserve an empty commit.  (If there were additional changes in branch `b1` I would not need the `-k` and the rest of the stuff below.)

```
$ git rebase -k master b1
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
HEAD detached from 40d9565
You are currently cherry-picking commit f603e15.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

If you wish to skip this commit, use:

    git reset

Then "git cherry-pick --continue" will resume cherry-picking
the remaining commits.
```

I want the empty commit (for illustration) so I follow the directions (adding `--no-edit` since I don't want to edit the commit message):

```
$ git commit --allow-empty --no-edit
[detached HEAD 3080d64] add file1
 Date: Thu Mar 17 11:18:51 2016 -0700
$ git cherry-pick --continue
$ git status
$ git status
HEAD detached from 40d9565
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Alas, I've run into a git bug!  I don't have time to fix the example so I'll just forcibly finish the rebase and make git do what it should have done here.  (If you don't understand this bit, don't worry about it, git should not have done what it just did and I'm working around it.)

```
$ git branch -f b1 HEAD && git checkout b1
Switched to branch 'b1'
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* 3080d64 (HEAD -> b1) add file1
* 71b0f5e (master) copy b1 file1 to common base
| * 01ef1ca (b2) add file2
|/  
* 40d9565 initial
```

Now I'll repeat with `b2`.  After rebasing, I will need to rename file2 to file1, though.

```
$ git rebase master b2
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: add file2
$ git rm file1 && git mv file2 file1 && git commit -m 'rename file2->file1'
rm 'file1'
[b2 435e6e7] rename file2->file1
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 18 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 file2
```

Let's view the commit graph:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
* 435e6e7 (HEAD -> b2) rename file2->file1
* 63a19b5 add file2
| * 3080d64 (b1) add file1
|/  
* 71b0f5e (master) copy b1 file1 to common base
* 40d9565 initial
```

Now I can do the merge on master (in two steps, and I need the `--no-ff` because `master` exactly matches `b1` because this example is perhaps *too* small / minimal):

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge --no-ff --no-edit b1
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
$ git merge --no-edit b2
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 file1 | 4 +++-
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

The merges are all done, but if we look at `file1` we have the wrong version: git thinks it should just use the `b2` version.

Let's unwind the mess and see what happens if we simply merge `b2` into `b1`, now that they have a common base:

```
$ git reset --hard 71b0f5e
HEAD is now at 71b0f5e copy b1 file1 to common base
```

(I cut-and-pasted the SHA-1 here, as it was still in a window; or I could use `master~2` since there are two merges to discard.)

```
$ git checkout b1
Switched to branch 'b1'
$ git merge --no-edit b2
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 file1 | 4 +++-
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Alas, as before (and this should be unsurprising, really), `file1` simply picks up `b2`'s changes and now matches the version in `b2`.  So let's toss this merge as well, and in fact, go back to the setup we had before we did all the rebasing, because this is the wrong approach.

Fortunately we still have all the initial commit IDs in the original `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` output.

```
$ git checkout master && git reset --hard 40d9565
Switched to branch 'master'
HEAD is now at 40d9565 initial
$ git checkout b1 && git reset --hard f603e15
Switched to branch 'b1'
HEAD is now at f603e15 add file1
$ git checkout b2 && git reset --hard 01ef1ca
Switched to branch 'b2'
HEAD is now at 01ef1ca add file2
```

(Note: it would be possible to do all this with the reflogs for `master`, `b1`, and `b2`, but as long as we have the raw SHA-1s handy, this was easier.)

#### The right way: `git merge-file`

Since we just want to manually merge `file1` and `file2` from the two branches, using "the empty file" as the common base version, we really just want to do exactly that.  First, let's get the two files into the work tree:

```
$ git show b1:file1 > file1
$ git show b2:file2 > file2
```

Now we tell `git merge-file` to use the empty file `/dev/null` as the common base:

```
$ git merge-file file1 /dev/null file2
```

The merge, in this case, finds conflicts between the items added, so we have to manually edit the result (in `file1`), but it now has the usual `<<<<<<<` style markers in it, which should make the merge easier.  (Also, remember to delete `file2` when done.)

If we had a better base file (than the empty `/dev/null`), `merge-file` could do a better job.  But in any case this is probably the way to go about it.

Comment: I followed your instructions for "The right way" for the files that originally prompted the question and I got an identical file to the one I got before. (I'm using git bash on windows and I got an error trying with `/dev/null/` so I made an empty file and used that instead. So this definitely works for my use-case. Assuming I don't care about keeping copies of file1 and file2 in a git repo, just using `git merge-file` as described seems to work just as well.